# Contract deployment on Polygon

Tags: contract-deployment, polygon

I am trying to deploy a smart contract. My RPC provider is Alchemy and I am working on Polygon and Mumbai.

When I try to deploy my contract on polygon it gives "**transaction underpriced**" error. The error is seen in the **polygon** network. When I try exactly the same steps for **mumbai** it works perfectly fine.

Can anybody help me what is going on? Why it is working for **mumbai** and not working for **polygon**. I have searched on the internet about **"transaction underpriced"** and understand what **it** is. However, I cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Up your gas price.  A lot of times errors you won't properly pull gas prices for polygon or testnets, so just check what current gas prices of other txns are and make sure you're above it to get mined

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try different values.